# How to take one column from a DataFrame & add it to an other Dataframe based on index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I Have two DataFrames:

Df1 , That Looks Like This:

```
Pollutants.head()

     Sensor_ID     Sensor_Street_Name     Sensor_Lat     Sensor_Long    Sensor_Type   UOM      Time_Instant

0     20020   Milano -via Carlo Pascal    45.478452      9.235016       Ammonia      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD

1     17127   Milano - viale Marche       45.496067      9.193023       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI

2     17126   Milano -via Carlo Pascal    45.478452      9.235016       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI

3     6057    Milano - via Senato         45.470780      9.197180       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI

4     6062    Milano - P.zza Zavattari    45.476089      9.143509       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI
```

And I have This DF2:

```
      Mi_Pollution.head()

      Sensor_ID      Time_Instant           Measurement
0     14121      2013-11-01 00:00:00        0.8
1     14121      2013-11-01 03:00:00        0.6
2     14121      2013-11-01 06:00:00        0.4
3     14121      2013-11-01 09:00:00        0.4
4     14121      2013-11-01 12:00:00         0
```

And What I want to do is , take the ***Sensor_Type*** Column & add it to the DF2 based on the ***Sensor_ID*** Column , like the desired ouput would be this one:

```
  Sensor_ID     Time_Instant        Measurement   Pollutants
0   20020    2015-11-01 00:00:00         0.3        Ammonia    
1   20020    2015-11-01 03:00:00         0.5        Ammonia
2   20020    2015-11-01 06:00:00         2.3        Ammonia
3   20020    2013-11-01 09:00:00         0.4        Ammonia
4   20020    2013-11-01 12:00:00          0         Ammonia
```

Any Suggestions ? , Thank U .

Answer (score 1):

you could use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this: (i have adapted the sample)

```
data1 = """
Sensor_ID     Sensor_Street_Name     Sensor_Lat     Sensor_Long    Sensor_Type   UOM      Time_Instant
14121   Milano-viaCarloPascal    45.478452      9.235016       Ammonia      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD
17127   Milano-vialeMarche       45.496067      9.193023       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD_HH24:MI
17126   Milano-viaCarloPascal    45.478452      9.235016       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD_HH24:MI
6057    Milano-viaSenato         45.470780      9.197180       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD_HH24:MI
6062    Milano-P.zzaZavattari    45.476089      9.143509       Benzene      µg/m      YYYY/MM/DD_HH24:MI
   """
data2 = """
Sensor_ID,Time_Instant,Measurement
14121,2013-11-01 00:00:00,0.8        
14121,2013-11-01 03:00:00,0.6        
14121,2013-11-01 06:00:00,0.4        
14121,2013-11-01 09:00:00,0.4        
17127,2013-11-01 12:00:00,0
                """

import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data2), sep=',')
```

---

```
s1 = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', on=['Sensor_ID'])
```

then, you drop the unused columns from the dataframe s1 and rename the column Sensor_Type to Pollutants and Time_Instant_x to Time_Instant

```
cols_to_delete = ['Sensor_Street_Name', 'Sensor_Lat','Sensor_Long','Time_Instant_y', 'UOM']
s1.drop(cols_to_delete, axis=1, inplace=True)
s1.rename(columns={'Time_Instant_x': 'Time_Instant', 'Sensor_Type': 'Pollutants'}, inplace=True)
```

with this sample result is :

```
       Sensor_ID         Time_Instant  Measurement Pollutants
0      14121  2013-11-01 00:00:00          0.8    Ammonia
1      14121  2013-11-01 03:00:00          0.6    Ammonia
2      14121  2013-11-01 06:00:00          0.4    Ammonia
3      14121  2013-11-01 09:00:00          0.4    Ammonia
4      17127  2013-11-01 12:00:00          0.0    Benzene
```

Comment: Thank's for the help , however after checking i get a column full of NaN's !!

Comment: all is NaN ?  you could have some NaN if you have Sensor_Id in DF2 which doesnt exist in DF1.. its normal...

Comment: the thing is , all is NaN !!

Comment: Sensor_ID are same type in both dataframe? show your program.. difficult to see why you have that..

Comment: you keep just 2 columns in df1, Sensor_ID and Sensor_Type, no need to have all columns to test

Comment: Indeed , in the DF1 'Sensor_ID' is an int64 where in the DF2 'Sensor_ID' is an object.

Comment: And Even by converting the 'Sensor_ID' into int , i still get a different result from what i was expecting !!